# Why does my Username and email not save in sql server (localhost)

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I was working on a register/log in page with a database (first time)
Whenever I register my user, I get the following information in the database:

[image]

It is giving me something like a password, but it won't give me my username and email (and i guess password aswell)

Can anyone help me with this?

My php code looks like this:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// connect to database

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'toolsforever');
if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    $username   = $db->real_escape_string($username);
    $password   = $db->real_escape_string($password);
    $password = md5($password); // hashed
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {    
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: home.php"); //redirect to home page
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Username/password combination incorrect";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance
PS: Password2 = confirm password for registration  password==password2 before they can register.

Comment: **Please do not store plain text passwords** nor hash it with weak algorithms, use the [password functions](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) provided by PHP.

Comment: `$username` and `$password` aren't defined. Did you mean $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] or similar? As for why is it empty in the DB? Well, you don't show us where it's inserted, so no idea.

Comment: Those fields are empty in your database, so what do you think you should be getting?

Comment: You're correct @JonStirling

Comment: I think i should get like $username = $_POST['username'] and $password = $_POST['password']. But like i said, i am new to all this and i have tried like 7 different login/register pages and most of them dont work or are too hard for a beginner (in my opinion)

Comment: You show us `select` query, but complain that `insert`ing is not working. Don't you think that it's better to show code with `insert` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the values from post array so do it like this:

```
$username   = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password   = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

I assume the form fields are names as `username` and `password`

It's not just related to retrieval, seems like you need to check the save operation as well. You are storing empty values during registration.

Answer (score 0):

That one worked @danyal Sandeelo.  I feel incredible stupid because i've tried an $_POST but i did it like: $username = $_POST['username']; $username = $db->real_escape_string;

Comment: I am glad it helped you out. Thanks.